# Significato di "essere a posto" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *Piombo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Me ne andavo giú lungo il torrente, un po’ sui massi, un po’ guadando dove si poteva, come un cane da caccia, con gli occhi inchiodati a terra, quando ecco, poco sotto alla confluenza di un altro torrente piú piccolo, ho visto un sasso in mezzo a milioni di altri sassi, [...]. L’ho raccolto, era pesante, [...]. [...]. 
>       A sera mi sono trovato un posto fuori mano, ho fatto un focolare, ci ho messo sopra il crogiolo ben stratificato, l’ho arroventato per mezz’ora e l’ho lasciato raffreddare. L’ho rotto, ed eccolo, il dischetto lucido e pesante, che si incide con l’unghia, quello che ti allarga il cuore e fa sparire dalle gambe la stanchezza del cammino, e che noi chiamiamo «il piccolo re».
>       A questo punto non è che uno **sia a posto**: anzi, il piú del lavoro è ancora da fare. Bisogna risalire il torrente, e ad ogni biforcazione cercare se la pietra buona continua a destra o a sinistra.

Dovete sapere che il narratore in questo racconto è un cercatore di piombo.

Non capisco del tutto bene cosa vuol dire l'espressione "non è che uno sia a posto" che appare in questo brano.

Alla [voce "posto" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/posto2/) ho trovato

> con riferimento a persone, *essere a p. col vestito, con i capelli*, ecc. (anche, *avere il vestito, i capelli a p*.), essere in ordine, esteriormente impeccabile; *siamo a posto!*, espressione che ha più significati, ma che in genere indica soddisfazione dello stato o della condizione raggiunti (anche con valore antifrastico e iron., con riferimento a situazioni poco piacevoli, critiche o addirittura disperate: *adesso che ci hanno rubato tutto, siamo a posto!*)

Quindi, il significato di "essere a posto" in questo contesto sarebbe "essere soddisfato dalla situazione"? Il narratore sta dicendo che non poteva essere soddisfatto poiché "il piú del lavoro" era "ancora da fare"?

Comment: @Hachi defininione perfetta, sarebbe da integrare nel Treccani.

Comment: Per quel che vale, da Roma questo specifico uso di “essere a posto” riferito a una persona anziché a una cosa mi suona lievemente settentrionale.

Comment: @Hachi: È vero, l'esempio del cameriere mi suona meno insolito, ma se sentissi una frase come “sei a posto con il tuo lavoro?” mi suonerebbe poco usuale. Sarei anche incerto sul significato: mi chiedono se mi piace il mio lavoro? se sono in regola? altro?

Answer (score 2):

La mia personale impressione è che “essere a posto”, così come è usato nel testo citato di Primo Levi, possa avere il senso di “aver fatto tutto quello che c’era da fare”. Il testo poi continua dicendo “il più del lavoro è da fare ancora”.

Dai commenti sembra che questo significato sia più tipicamente usato al nord.

Answer (score 0):

Concordo con la definizione del vocabolario Treccani menzionata sopra, ma mi suona molto pertinente anche la seguente definizione, tratta dalla stessa voce di vocabolario (anche se c'è il verbo *mettere* e non *essere*, le parole utilizzate mi danno proprio il senso di "essere a posto"):

> mettere tutto a p., sistemare definitivamente, risolvere problemi, questioni, situazioni complesse, appianando ogni difficoltà, chiarendo eventuali malintesi

Il narratore sta dicendo che non poteva essere soddisfatto poiché non aveva risolto tutti i problemi.

In pratica "essere a posto" si può semplicemente intendere come "stare bene, senza problemi";
infatti, spessissimo, quando si incontra qualcuno (almeno nel sud Italia), invece di chiedere "Tutto bene?", si chiede "Tutto a posto?"

Comment: L’espressione da commentare è “essere a posto”  non “mettere a posto”. I significati sono diversi. Btw anche al nord e molto comune chiedere  “tutto a posto“?